# How do I sleep for a certain number of milliseconds?

Tags: c#, timespan, thread-sleep

I have searched everywhere and im puzzled sorry if this sounds so ridiculous but i cant just find anywhere how to do it i always get debug errors with invalid types etc

I got a simple numeric and I want it to have # of seconds then i want to do a thread sleep for X milliseconds

how the heck do I convert this ? I have tried everything my last attempt was below which is wrong for once more.
 help me please cheers

```
// int countnumeric = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(numericUpDown1.Value, 0));

var timeSpan = new TimeSpan((long)numericUpDown1.Value);

MessageBox.Show("sleeping for milliseconds - " + Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds, 0)));

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds, 0))); ///////**
```

Comment: There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond. You want to use: `var timeSpan = new TimeSpan((long)numericUpDown1.Value * 10000);` **then** use @Pretasoc's solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2) struct has some very useful methods for creating TimeSpans, you are looking for [`TimeSpan.FromSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var timeToSleep = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(numericUpDown1.Value));

Thread.Sleep(timeToSleep);
```

If you are in an asynchronous method you can use:

```
await Task.Delay(timeToSleep);
```

Comment: Note the OP says _I got a simple numeric and I want it to have # of seconds …_which suggests that `numericUpDown1` holds a number of seconds, not a number of milliseconds.  In which case you'd want to use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds()` not `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds()`.

Comment: numericUpDown1.Value is in seconds so why accept it as input in TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds ??

Comment: cheers also it needs a double also as it seems :P TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)numericUpDown1.Value

Comment: Whoops! fixed it! :)

Comment: @kostas Converting from `Decimal` to `double` can result in a loss of precision so C# won't do the conversion implicitly (so that you don't lose precision accidentally) .  Instead it [insists you use a casting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.todouble?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) or the [`Decimal.ToDouble()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.todouble?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) method.

Comment: @FrankBoyne is right, another way to do it is to use [`Convert.ToDouble(numericUpDown1.Value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for Converting. `Thread.Sleep` provides an overload that takes an `TimeSpan` as an duration parameter. so you can call `Thread.Sleep(timeSpan);`.

Comment: So i tried that and i put a messagebox to test how many milliseconds are passed if i select say 5 seconds in numeric via the timespan and i get 00:00:00.0000005 so this is passed to threadsleep ?? i put this             MessageBox.Show("sleeping for milliseconds - " + timeSpan);

Comment: @kostasm The constructor you're using takes Ticks (100 ns) not seconds. Maybe you'll use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(numericalUpDown.Value)`

Comment: i did thanks but now it gives for 10 secs 00:00:10 as output does threadsleep accept that ??? should it not output 10000 ? cheers

Comment: @kostasm Yes. The string representation of the `TimeSpan` is just a human readable representation. `TimeSpan` internally only saves the amount of ticks. `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)` "knows" how to use that information.